# How to typedef a tuple that is concatenation of other tuples?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class A{ typedef tuple<int, double, int> list; };
class B{ typedef tuple<int, int> list; };
class C{ typedef tuple<int, double, char> list; };

template <typename... args>
    class My_class{
          //need a tuple type that is combination of all the tuple named list in the class A B C
    };

    My_class<A, B, C> obj;
```

How do i create a typedef with in My_class so that it is equal to `tuple<int, double, int, int, int, int, double, char>` ?

Comment: [std::tuple_cat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can make `A::list`, `B::list` and `C::list` publicly accessible, what you want is:

```
template <typename... Args>
class My_class{
    typedef decltype(tuple_cat(declval<typename Args::list>()...)) list; 
};
```

It looks ugly, but unfortunately there isn't a way to join tuple types in the C++ standard.  You could make your own `tuple_flatten` as such:

```
template <typename... Tuple>
struct tuple_flatten{
    typedef decltype(tuple_cat(declval<Tuple>()...)) type; 
};
template <typename... Tuple>
using tuple_flatten_t = typename tuple_flatten<Tuple...>::type;
```

To use:

```
template <typename... Args>
class My_class{
    typedef typename tuple_flatten<typename Args::list...>::type list; 
};
```

Also, by most conventions, type parameters (`Args`) should start with a capital letter.